# Dynamic clicked button - access dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button `thumb` that is created later (not exist when document load),

```
$(document).on('click', '.thumb', function(){
  console.log("clicked",$(".productPhoto"),$(this).attr("src"));
```

The issue is that `productPhoto` is also being created later, and although **i can click the thumb**, if i try to print `productPhoto`, i get nothing, but the element is there when i click.

Is there a way to access also an element that is being created later (on click)?
(*without* registering it for click on creation)

Comment: Could you please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: it will be hard to create this demo because i am adding elements later based on user interaction. To clarify, think that 1 minute after we open the page, i create an element called productPhoto, and also Thumb. Then when you click the Thumb i would like get access to productPhoto. So, i can click the thumb, but can't access productPhoto ( guess because the code inside the click function happens on document creating)

Comment: You don't need to recreate full app for the demo, you can add items dynamically like `$("#mydiv").append("<div class='thumb'>Thumb</div>");` and `$("#mydiv").append("<div class='productPhoto'>productPhoto</div>");` and try to see if now you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: If the element exists when you click, it should log it. It doesn't matter that it's created dynamically, you're not calling it until the click occurs.

Comment: Are you sure you want to log the whole jQuery object, not something like its value or an attribute?

Comment: What you've written *should* work. So there must be something else in your code that's interfering, and if you don't post a [mcve] we can't tell what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

try calling dynamic elements using parent static elements as prefix
eg:  `$("#div1 .foo")`